# Python Pandas - Return number of values under a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with an excel file with has a column called `'HEIGHT'`.

I would like to return the number of values in this column.

There are blank values in this column, so I would only like the count of actual numbers.

I have tried `df['HEIGHT']` however it returns all the rows even if they don't have a value.

I also would like to know how to delete all the rows that don't have a value in the `'HEIGHT'` column.

Comment: What do you mean with 'don't have' are you getting `NaN` as inputs or blanks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove NaN/NULL columns in a Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857924/remove-nan-null-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @CeliusStingher I am getting NaN as inputs, I guess I could filter find the number of NaN values and subtract it from the length of the array to get the total number of values, but that seems inefficient.

Comment: I am not upvoting your question due to not providing a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to adress two different situations, one in which you are getting `NaN` as values for the column `height` and another one when you get a blank space.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Situation 1:

```
data = {'Height':[100,110,104,np.NaN,200,np.NaN],'Name':['Franky','Coby','Robin','Kanjuro','Tom','Ace']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Solution 1:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['Height'],axis=0)
values = df['Height'].tolist()
print(values)
```

Situation 2:

```
data = {'Height':[100,110,104,'',200,''],'Name':['Franky','Coby','Robin','Kanjuro','Tom','Ace']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Solution 2:

```
df['Height'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Height'],errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna(subset=['Height'],axis=0)
values = df['Height'].tolist()
print(values)
```

Both outputs are:

```
[100.0, 110.0, 104.0, 200.0]
```

Comment: I just tried this on my data frames, unfortunately it just deleted the whole data frame because there are NaN values in other columns. But I just wanted to delete the rows that have NaN values in the "HEIGHT" column.

Comment: Sure, you just need to use the parameter `subset=['Height']` edited in answer aswell.

Comment: Thank's for this, I just realized I could also do `df = df[np.isfinite(df['HEIGHT'])]`