# Remove the empty columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

how to remove empty columns in pandas data frame. However, these empty columns does not have any NaN values.
I have the this type of output after running the dataframe. I want to remove these empty columns which are attached in image. In my dataframe there is no NaN or NA values only empty entries.

Comment: I think you should check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857924/remove-nan-null-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe) out

Comment: This link is helpful, but my dataframe columns donot have NaN values. They are empty.

Comment: can you provide a sample of your dataframe

Comment: The links mentioned above also have solutions for `null` values, have you tried those solutions or something similar?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but for these links, NA values should be present, then it can remove.

Comment: There is no such thing as "*empty*" cells, you need to provide a sample for explicitness. What is the output of `df.head().to_dict()` ([edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71643477/edit) your question)? The only case where columns can be empty is if there are no rows. In which case removing empty columns would be removing the whole dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all i would like to recommend you to replace the `' '` values by `'NaN'`

```
df['Name'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

After that u can use basic function drop

```
df.dropna(subset=['Name'], inplace=True)
```